# Getting twitter account list in IOS-5 and user it with TWTweetComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter

i am using Twitter with IOS - 5 integration. i used tweeting app provide by apple for this.I am using TWTweetComposeViewController for this.

But if i have more than 2 twitter accounts. it is getting my first account every time. but i want that list of my different account shown to me and then when i select one of account and then i can use it with  TWTweetComposeViewController. i like to show like bellow image From :"username"

i have used this code :

```
 - (IBAction)sendEasyTweet:(id)sender {
// Set up the built-in twitter composition view controller.
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

// Set the initial tweet text. See the framework for additional properties that can be set.
[tweetViewController setInitialText:@"Hello. This is a tweet."];
[tweetViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]];


// Create the completion handler block.
[tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    NSString *output;

    switch (result) {
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            // The cancel button was tapped.
            output = @"Tweet cancelled.";
            break;
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            // The tweet was sent.
            output = @"Tweet done.";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];

    // Dismiss the tweet composition view controller.
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];

// Present the tweet composition view controller modally.
[self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now , i am getting my it , and picker is showing for it as shown in image[image]

so from this picker , i can select one of my account for tweet.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `TWTweetComposeViewController` doesn't give you much configuration flexibility. If you tap on the account name it will pop up your list of accounts. `TWTweetCVC` does seem to remember the last account you tweeted with though.

If you use `ACAccountStore` you can get the list of the users Twitter accounts and you could provide your own UI to choose one but you cannot configure `TWTweetComposeViewController` to use it. If you couple that with `TWRequest` you can roll your own tweet sheet class and do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController) is a drop-in replacement for TWTweetComposeViewController. It's open source, so you can modify it to meet your needs. It's also compatible with iOS 4.