# Twitter user id in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I'm using the following code to get the user details from Twitter in iOS 5.

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) 
{
    // Create account store, followed by a Twitter account identifer
    account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
     {
         // Did user allow us access?
         if (granted == YES)
         {
             // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
             arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
             [arrayOfAccounts retain];

             // Populate the tableview
             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) 
                 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTableview) withObject:NULL waitUntilDone:NO];
         }
     }];
}

//

-(void)updateTableview
{

    numberOfTwitterAccounts = [arrayOfAccounts count];
    NSLog(@"Twiter details-- %@",[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0]);

}
```

In my `NSLog` console, I am getting the output as follows:

```
Twiter details-- type:com.apple.twitter  
identifier: E8591841-2AE0-4FC3-8ED8-F286BE7A36B0
accountDescription: @Sadoo55
username: sadukoyghdkwed@gmail.com
objectID: x-coredata://F8059811-CFB2-4E20-BD88-F4D06A43EF11/Account/p8
enabledDataclasses: {(
)}
properties: {
  "user_id" = 308905856;
}
parentAccount: (null)
owningBundleID:com.apple.Preferences
```

I want to get the "user_id" from this. How can I fetch "user_id" (ie. 308905856)?

Comment: Oh come on, this is your 19th question, you should know how to format your question by now.

Comment: Thnak u @Maulik.i Will correct next time:

Comment: Try this: NSLog(@"%@", [[[arrayOfAccounts objectForKey:@"properties"] valueForKey:@"user_id"] objectAtIndex:0]);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Getting the user ID &/or username is *much* easier than that.

### iOS 7 version

```
ACAccount *account = accountsArray[0];
NSString *userID = ((NSDictionary*)[account valueForKey:@"properties"])[@"user_id"];
```

*or*

```
ACAccount *twitterAccount = accountsArray[0];
NSRange range = [account.description rangeOfString:@" [0-9]{7,8}"
                                           options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
  NSString *userID = [[account.description substringWithRange:range] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
  NSLog(@"User ID: %@", userID);
}
```

### iOS 5 version

There was an undocumented method of ACAccount called accountProperties of type NSDictionary with a user_id key.

[image: ACAccount properties]

```
ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *userID = [[twitterAccount accountProperties] objectForKey:@"user_id"];
NSString *username = twitterAccount.username;
```

**Does not work under iOS6 because the method is no longer defined.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As it is very apparent in the debug log output in the question, identifier is not the same as user_id.

Comment: @cirrosstrauts  The Updated answer is correct. But am getting a warning that " instance method '-accountProperties' not found (return type defaults to 'id') " Any way thanks to ur answer..

Comment: There is no such property "accountProperty"

Comment: @runmad It's `accountProperties` and it was an undocumented property as of that post.

Comment: @Cirrostratus - No visible interface for 'ACAccount' declares the selector 'accountProperties' is most likely what runmad was talking about. I receive the same error.

Answer (score 20):

Here's what I did to get the user_id in iOS5 and iOS6.

```
    NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: 
                                     [twitterAccount dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"properties"]]];
    NSString *tempUserID = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"properties"] objectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

Comment: Then wouldn't `[twitterAccount valueForKeyPath:@"properties.user_id"]` do the same thing without an intermediate dictionary?

Answer (score 14):

You can think account object like a dictionary and perform this:

```
ACAccount *account = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *userID = [account valueForKeyPath:@"properties.user_id"];
```

This will return user_id

Answer (score -5):

I guess the problem is in the flow of your coding. Please re-check it with the below links.
The error seems to be a more framework related error.
I would suggest you to go through the following tutorial which i found best on web once:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-5-twitter-framework-part-1.html

Plus, this one is also awesome with a lot of detail and simplified explanation from Ray.
I follow his blog for same.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5

Comment: I dont think twitter gives you the flexibility for getting user-id for  twitter. Check this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth . See this also in the same context with regard to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543015/getting-twitter-account-list-in-ios-5-and-user-it-with-twtweetcomposeviewcontrol. As far as i came across the posts online i would say one word we can't access user-id, twitter doesn't give flexibility for its inside API. Think you can't get that :(

Comment: Its giving a JSON response. Extract it in some NSDictionary and get the[dictionary valueForKey:@"properties"]valueForKey:@"user_id"];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7201/discussion-between-aksani56-and-sadumerry)

Comment: Since she is using iOS 5, there is built-in JSON support in the NSJSONSerialization class.